# I got new connection every page refresh

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, hikaricp

If in a simple jsp I call PoolDataSource.getConnection() and use it for a query I can get data, but if I refresh the page the 'MaximumPoolSize' times I get timeout error, so it seems that the pool use a connection for every page refresh and not reuse it.

HikariCP version: HikariCP-3.3.1
JDK version     : 1.8.0_191
Database        : MySQL
Driver version  : mariadb-java-client-2.4.0 ; mysql-connector-java-8.0.15
Tomcat version : 9.0.13

Hi, I'm trying to replace Apache Torque in my web application, I'd like to use standard ResultSets on a connection Pool.
I've made a startup servlet that reads database connection info from a file, this servlet runs one time on Tomcat startup, so the connection information is available.
After that I've made a java class that use the connection information to initiate an HikariDataSource like this:

```
        public class PoolDataSource {
            private static HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
            private static HikariDataSource ds ;
            private static String lastError = "";

            public static void init () {
                try {
                    // leggo le impostazioni
                    if (DataConfig.isReady()) {
                        lastError = "";
                        config.setMaximumPoolSize(50);
                        config.setMinimumIdle(5);
                        config.setPoolName("MainPool");
                        config.setDataSourceClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource");
                        config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", DataConfig.getHost());
                        config.addDataSourceProperty("port", DataConfig.getPort());
                        config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", DataConfig.getDatabasename());
                        config.addDataSourceProperty("properties", "useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf8");
                        config.setUsername(DataConfig.getUsername());
                        config.setPassword(DataConfig.getPassword());
                        config.setIdleTimeout(1000);
                        config.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
                        config.setLeakDetectionThreshold(2000);
                        config.setMaxLifetime(7000);


                        ds = new HikariDataSource(config);

                        if (isConnected()) {
                            // controllo il database per vedere se esiste la struttura ed i dati base


                        }
                    } else {
                        Logger.Warning("---- Percorso base non settato ----", 0);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    lastError = ex.toString();
                    Logger.Error(ex, "---- Errore in connessione al database ----", 0);
                }
            }

            public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
                return ds.getConnection();
            }
        }
```

I'd like to get a connection object that I can use directly in my jsp pages but now after some refresh it ends responding.

Thanks

Comment: you have to `close()` the connections after you stop using them. A s a rule of tumb you should keep the connections for as short time as possible.

Comment: Look into using Spring Data Access library for much easier / simpler logic for accessing databases. It can handle connections for you

Comment: Ok, I've to close it, now it works!! Many thanks Svetlin!